# How do I get installing apps package name?

Tags: android

I have a  list of apk files in SDcard.  It  shows its' name and icon; everything works fine.

This app  shows a list of uninstall apk files which are in Sdcrd,  when user install any Apk from this list its' package name will save on database so when user goes to another screen that will show only that application which area install from SD card.

How do I get the name of apk file which the user clicks to install from list?

This is my code:

```
    public class SdcardAPkMgr extends ListActivity {

private List<FileInformation> files_list;
private ProgressDialog mLoadDialog;
private Handler handler;
private static final int SCAN_APK_START = 101;
private static final int SCAN_APK_COMLETED = 102;
private boolean mJustCreate = true;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apk_list);
    files_list = new ArrayList<FileInformation>();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setupBatchHandler();
    if (mJustCreate) {
        thread.start();
    }
    mJustCreate = false;
}

private void setupBatchHandler() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    handler = new Handler() {
        // @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case SCAN_APK_START: {
                mLoadDialog = 
 ProgressDialog.show(SdcardAPkMgr.this, "",
                        getString(R.string.scan_apk_info));
                mLoadDialog.setCancelable(false);
                break;
            }
            case SCAN_APK_COMLETED: {
                ApkListAdapter adapter = new ApkListAdapter(
                        SdcardAPkMgr.this, files_list);
                SdcardAPkMgr.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
                mLoadDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(SCAN_APK_START);
        getAllApkFiles(new File("/sdcard"));
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(SCAN_APK_COMLETED);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FileInformation information = files_list.get(position);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(information.getPath())), 
   "application/" +
                        "vnd.android.package-archive");
        this.startActivity(intent);
}

public Drawable getAPKDrawable(String filePath) {
    Drawable dr = null;
    if (filePath != null) {

        String PATH_PackageParser = "android.content.pm.PackageParser";
        String PATH_AssetManager = "android.content.res.AssetManager";
        try {
            Class pkgParserCls = Class.forName(PATH_PackageParser);
            Class[] typeArgs = new Class[1];
            typeArgs[0] = String.class;
            Constructor pkgParserCt = pkgParserCls.getConstructor(typeArgs);
            Object[] valueArgs = new Object[1];
            valueArgs[0] = filePath;
            Object pkgParser = pkgParserCt.newInstance(valueArgs);
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            metrics.setToDefaults();
            // PackageParser.Package mPkgInfo =
            // packageParser.parsePackage(new
            // File(apkPath), apkPath,
            // metrics, 0);
            typeArgs = new Class[4];
            typeArgs[0] = File.class;
            typeArgs[1] = String.class;
            typeArgs[2] = DisplayMetrics.class;
            typeArgs[3] = Integer.TYPE;
            Method pkgParser_parsePackageMtd = pkgParserCls
                    .getDeclaredMethod("parsePackage", 

typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[4];
            valueArgs[0] = new File(filePath);
            valueArgs[1] = filePath;
            valueArgs[2] = metrics;
            valueArgs[3] = 0;
            Object pkgParserPkg = pkgParser_parsePackageMtd.invoke(
                    pkgParser, valueArgs);
            Field appInfoFld = 
pkgParserPkg.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                    "applicationInfo");
            ApplicationInfo info = (ApplicationInfo) appInfoFld 
  .get(pkgParserPkg);

            Class assetMagCls = Class.forName(PATH_AssetManager);
            Constructor assetMagCt = assetMagCls
                    .getConstructor((Class[]) null);
            Object assetMag = assetMagCt.newInstance((Object[]) null);
            typeArgs = new Class[1];
            typeArgs[0] = String.class;
            Method assetMag_addAssetPathMtd = assetMagCls
                    .getDeclaredMethod("addAssetPath", typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[1];
            valueArgs[0] = filePath;
            assetMag_addAssetPathMtd.invoke(assetMag, valueArgs);
            Resources res = getResources();
            typeArgs = new Class[3];
            typeArgs[0] = assetMag.getClass();
            typeArgs[1] = res.getDisplayMetrics().getClass();
            typeArgs[2] = res.getConfiguration().getClass();
            Constructor resCt = 
   Resources.class.getConstructor(typeArgs);
            valueArgs = new Object[3];
            valueArgs[0] = assetMag;
            valueArgs[1] = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            valueArgs[2] = res.getConfiguration();
            res = (Resources) resCt.newInstance(valueArgs);
            CharSequence label = null;
            if (info.labelRes != 0) {
                label = res.getText(info.labelRes);
            }
            if (info.icon != 0) {
                dr = res.getDrawable(info.icon);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (dr == null) {
        dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_apk_icon);
    }
    return dr;
}

private void getAllApkFiles(File root) {

    File files[] = root.listFiles();

    if (files != null)
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                getAllApkFiles(f);
            } else {
                if (f.getName().indexOf(".apk") > 0) {
                    // this.list.add(f);
                    String path = f.toString();
                    String name = 
  path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            path.length());
                    this.files_list.add(new 
   FileInformation(name, path,
                            getAPKDrawable(path)));
                }
            }
        }

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

APK is actually a zip file so you can just open it and read the package name from `AndroidManifest.xml`

Be aware the file is not plain and decoded somehow, but it's there

Comment: how i know package name without installling application?

Comment: you don't need to install, just uncompress the apk

Comment: no actuly i m creating and application which load apk filesfrom sdcard and install them and show only thats apps inlistview which load from sd card not all application